# How to keep running even if AngularJS module failed to load

Tags: angularjs

example:

```
angular.module("app", ['someServices'])
```

if `someServices` not exist, will get error message:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module pascalprecht.translate32 due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'someServices' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

But now, I want to keep it running, meaning that if it load failed then ignore it.

Is there has some config for this?

Comment: Why you inject something that doesnt exists? I dont get the point of doing something like that.

Comment: The module load from other person's config. Maybe the guy make a mistake:)
When this happens we just want to remind him, not let the application stop.

Answer (score 1):

I still don't get why you need to do this. But there is no way around it depending on AngularJS alone. If you want to do something like this, you could always check for the module's existence first and not include it in the dependencies if it does not exist. Something like this:

```
var dependencies = [];
if (angular.module('someServices')) dependencies.push( 'someServices' );
var myApp = angular.module("app", dependencies);
```

Comment: I have a good example. A dependency of an angular module is falling victim to a bug in a specific browser. This module is not a core function. I want to minimize the impact of this module failing to load so the rest of the app can do so.